# Communication between a desktop application and a web application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms-to-web

I have a desktop and web application connected to same database.
Which is the most preferred method to make them communicate with each other?

Comment: Why do they need to communicate with each other?  If each one ensures that their database transactions are atomic and that they are always using locks properly, there should be no problem at all with both apps accessing the same database with no communication necessary.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to make sure both apps follow the same business rules? Are you trying to automate a browser session? maybe you want a web application to fire up a desktop application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `SOA` and then both your desktop app and web app should communicate with the Service.

And the `Service` will be responsible for communicating with the database.